# Choosing suitable camera for barcode scanning when using AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTripleCamera

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, barcode-scanner

I've had some barcode scanning code in my iOS app for many years now. Recently, users have begun complaining that it doesn't work with an iPhone 13 Pro.

During investigation, it seemed that I should be using the built in triple camera if available. Doing that *did* fix it for iPhone 13 Pro but subsequently broke it for iPhone 12 Pro, which seemed to be working fine with the previous code.

How are you supposed to choose a suitable camera for all devices? It seems bizarre to me that Apple has suddenly made it so difficult to use this previously working code.

Here is my current code. The "fallback" section is what the code has used for years.

```
     _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
     // Must use macro camera for barcode scanning on newer devices, otherwise the image is blurry
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession * discoverySession =
        [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTripleCamera]
                                                               mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
        if (discoverySession.devices.count == 0) {
            // no BuiltInTripleCamera
            _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        } else {
            _device = discoverySession.devices.firstObject;
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }
```

Comment: I think I have a similar issue -- the "minimum distance" has gone from about 3" (for iPh 6 & 8) and 3.75 (iPh 13 Pro) to about 5.75" for iPhone 14 Pro.  I haven't changed any code yet.

Comment: Hopefully somebody has a generic solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully with the help of reddit I was able to figure out that the solution is simply to replace

```
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTripleCamera
```

with

```
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works but not all the time. Because lenses have different minimum focus distance it is harder for the device to focus on small barcodes because you have to put you device too close (before the minimum focus distance). This way it will never autofocus on small barcodes. It used to work on older lenses where autofocus was 10-12 cm but newer lenses especially those on iPhone 14 Pros that have the distance 20cm will be problematic.

The solution is to use ideally `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera` and setting `videoZoomFactor` on the `AVCaptureDevice` to zoom in little bit so the barcode will be nicely focused. The value should be calculated based on the input video properties and minimum size of barcode.

For details please refer to this WWDC 2019 video where they address exactly this issue https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10047/?time=133.

Here is implementation of class that sets zoom factor on a device that works for me. You can instantiate this class providing your device instance and call `applyAutomaticZoomFactorIfNeeded()` just before you are about to commit your capture session configuration.

```
///
/// Calling this method will automatically zoom the device to increase minimum focus distance. This distance appears to be problematic
/// when scanning barcodes too small or if a device's minimum focus distance is too large (like on iPhone 14 Pro and Max - 20cm, iPhone 13 Pro - 15 cm, older iPhones 12 or less.). By zooming
/// the input the device will be able to focus on a preview and complete the scan more easily.
///
/// - See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10047/?time=133 for more detailed explanation and
/// - See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcambarcode_detecting_barcodes_and_faces
/// for implementation instructions.
///
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
final class DeviceAutomaticVideoZoomFactor {
   
    enum Errors : Error {
        case minimumFocusDistanceUnknown
        case deviceLockFailed
    }
    
    private let device: AVCaptureDevice
    private let minimumCodeSize: Float
    
    init(device: AVCaptureDevice, minimumCodeSize: Float) {
        self.device = device
        self.minimumCodeSize = minimumCodeSize
    }
    
    ///
    /// Optimize the user experience for scanning QR codes down to smaller sizes (determined by `minimumCodeSize`, for example 2x2 cm).
    /// When scanning a QR code of that size, the user may need to get closer than the camera's minimum focus distance to fill the rect of interest.
    /// To have the QR code both fill the rect and still be in focus, we may need to apply some zoom.
    ///
    func applyAutomaticZoomFactorIfNeeded() throws {
        
        let deviceMinimumFocusDistance = Float(self.device.minimumFocusDistance)
        guard deviceMinimumFocusDistance != -1 else {
            throw Errors.minimumFocusDistanceUnknown
        }
        
        Logger.logIfStaging("Video Zoom Factor", "using device: \(self.device)")
        
        Logger.logIfStaging("Video Zoom Factor", "device minimum focus distance: \(deviceMinimumFocusDistance)")
        
        /*
            Set an inital square rect of interest that is 100% of the view's shortest side.
            This means that the region of interest will appear in the same spot regardless
            of whether the app starts in portrait or landscape.
        */
        let formatDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(self.device.activeFormat.formatDescription)
        let rectOfInterestWidth = Double(formatDimensions.height) / Double(formatDimensions.width)
        
        let deviceFieldOfView = self.device.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView
        let minimumSubjectDistanceForCode = self.minimumSubjectDistanceForCode(fieldOfView: deviceFieldOfView,
                                                                               minimumCodeSize: self.minimumCodeSize,
                                                                               previewFillPercentage: Float(rectOfInterestWidth))
        
        Logger.logIfStaging("Video Zoom Factor", "minimum subject distance: \(minimumSubjectDistanceForCode)")
        
        guard minimumSubjectDistanceForCode < deviceMinimumFocusDistance else {
            return
        }
        
        let zoomFactor = deviceMinimumFocusDistance / minimumSubjectDistanceForCode
        
        Logger.logIfStaging("Video Zoom Factor", "computed zoom factor: \(zoomFactor)")
        
        try self.device.lockForConfiguration()
        self.device.videoZoomFactor = CGFloat(zoomFactor)
        self.device.unlockForConfiguration()
        
        Logger.logIfStaging("Video Zoom Factor", "applied zoom factor: \(self.device.videoZoomFactor)")
    }
    
    private func minimumSubjectDistanceForCode(fieldOfView: Float,
                                               minimumCodeSize: Float,
                                               previewFillPercentage: Float) -> Float {
        /*
            Given the camera horizontal field of view, we can compute the distance (mm) to make a code
            of minimumCodeSize (mm) fill the previewFillPercentage.
         */
        let radians = self.degreesToRadians(fieldOfView / 2)
        let filledCodeSize = minimumCodeSize / previewFillPercentage
        return filledCodeSize / tan(radians)
    }
    
    private func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> Float {
        return degrees * Float.pi / 180
    }
}
```

Comment: So I started getting reports of it not working for certain users, and then I tried your solution. It fixed some of them but for iPhone 14 pro it still looks very blurry up close (but works when the camera is far away). Any ideas?

I'm using it "minimumCodeSize:20.7264f" for the min size of a barcode (.816 inches)

```

Comment: Changed it 40 and put it right before the session is finalized and seems to work better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ObjectiveC version of @tankista's excellent answer:

Modeled after the WWDC video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10047/?time=133. See also their BarCode example app here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcambarcode_detecting_barcodes_and_faces?language=objc

static CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = self.videoCamera.inputCamera; // you'll replace this RHS expression with your video device
    int deviceFieldOfView = videoDevice.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView;
    float previewFillPercentage = 0.8; // 0..1, target object will fill 80% of preview window
    float minimumTargetObjectSize = 15.0 * 10.0; // min width of target object in mm (here, it's 15 cm)
    float radians = DegreesToRadians(deviceFieldOfView);
    float filledTargetObjectSize = minimumTargetObjectSize / previewFillPercentage;
    int minimumSubjectDistance = filledTargetObjectSize / tan(radians / 2.0); // Field of View equation

    NSInteger deviceMinimumFocusDistance = videoDevice.minimumFocusDistance;
    
    if (minimumSubjectDistance < deviceMinimumFocusDistance) {
        float zoomFactor = deviceMinimumFocusDistance / minimumSubjectDistance;
        [videoDevice lockForConfiguration: NULL];
        [videoDevice setVideoZoomFactor:zoomFactor];
        [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }
} else {
    // No API to help here, but these phones won't have macro lenses
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use BuiltInTripleCamera as device type, our App will use Ultra Wide Camera as active primary device. But iPhone 12 Pro don't support Macro Photography so this device don't work well.

You should set device.videoZoomFactor = device.virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors.first.
To let Wide Angle camera can be active primary device. And let iPhone choose camera auto.

```
     guard let virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactor = input.device.virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors.first as? CGFloat else {
            return
        }
        try? input.device.lockForConfiguration()
        input.device.videoZoomFactor = virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactor
        input.device.unlockForConfiguration()
```

You can see document about it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureprimaryconstituentdevicerestrictedswitchingbehaviorconditions
[Screenshot of key information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrdFB.png)